# When using match operator on a variable declaration using qq, why do the parentheses work around the declaration itself?

Tags: perl

I know the title is a mouthful but I wasn't sure how to make it more succinct.

Reading up on multiline strings in Perl I came across this post at [PerlMaven about here-documents](https://perlmaven.com/here-documents). It talks about here-documents, `qq` and `q`. In all cases leading whitespace, like that used for code indentation, is retained. I understand that. The way this is mitigated in the example show is using a regex replacement to remove the leading spaces.

> ```
> if ($send) {
>     (my $message = qq{
>         Dear $name,
>
>         this is a message I plan to send to you.
>
>         regards
>           the Perl Maven
>         }) =~ s/^ {8}//mg;
>     print $message;
> }
> ```

When I was trying to adopt this style I wrote it like this (accidentally) instead:

```
if ($send) {
    my $message = (qq{
        Dear $name,
          words and stuff
        }) =~ s/^ {8}//mg;
    print $message;
}
```

Perl is not a strong language for me. The *incorrect* syntax I tried above seemed natural to me though. Since I am using the match operator incorrectly I obviously get the error:

> Can't modify string in substitution (s///) at nagios_send_html_service_mail.pl line 91, near "s/^ {8}//mg;"

In the working example *why* does the `$message` actual contain the changes? I seems like something you are allowed to do when you declare variables but I just wanted to know what it was called.

Comment: Note that the next Perl release (5.26) will likely include _indented HERE docs_. Here's [the thread about it on p5p](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2016/07/msg237489.html) and [this is the new Pumpkin SawyerX talking about it in a talk at YAPC::EU 2015](https://youtu.be/LlhhyeXQgMo?t=44m41s). (I recommend the full talk, it has newish features as well as planned changes and is well worth the time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's about what you're trying to change.

`=~` is the binding operator, and tells you what to apply the pattern match to.

```
my $message = "fish";
   $message =~ s/i/a/; 
print $message
```

Will work, because you're trying to transform `$message`. This is what's happening in the first example - message is being set *first*, and then the modification is applied, because of the brackets.

However, `=~` is tighter binding that `=`. It happens first.

This precedence is documented in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity)

So in the first example - the assignment happens first because of the brackets, and then transform. Without the brackets, it tries the transform first:

```
"fish" =~ s/i/a/;
```

Which is invalid, because it's not changing a variable at that point, but a static piece of text.

```
my $result = "fish" =~ s/i/a/; #gives same error.
( my $result = "fish" ) =~ s/i/a/; #works.
```

You could do this another way (if your version of perl is new enough) by using the `r` regex modifier, to return a value:

```
my $result = "fish" =~ s/i/a/r;
```

The `r` flag stops trying to modify the value, and just 'returns' the result of the operation, which then can be assigned to `$result`.

Comment: So it is dependent on the order of binding.... Ok. Thanks. Is there a reference for that order? It makes more sense as well when I just look at it as static text (which is what qq was doing.)

Comment: Yes: [Perl operator precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity)

Answer (score 5):

`=~` has higher precedence than `=`, so

```
my $message = (qq{...}) =~ s/^ {8}//mg;
```

is equivalent to

```
my $message = ( (qq{...}) =~ s/^ {8}//mg );
```

This tries to modify the constant returned by `qq`, which is not allowed.

---

A scalar assignment operator in scalar context returns its left-hand side (as an lvalue)<sup>[1]</sup>. That means

```
( $message = qq{...} ) =~ s/^ {8}//mg;
```

is equivalent to

```
$message = qq{...};
$message =~ s/^ {8}//mg;
```

Furthermore, `my $message` returns `$message` (as an lvalue), so

```
( my $message = qq{...} ) =~ s/^ {8}//mg;
```

is equivalent to

```
my $message;
$message = qq{...};
$message =~ s/^ {8}//mg;
```

This is why the original solution worked.

---

Note that indenting changes will break your code, so your technique is fragile. Consider using the following instead:

```
if ($send) {
    (my $message = qq{
        !Dear $name,
        !
        !this is a message I plan to send to you.
        !
        !regards
        !  the Perl Maven
    }) =~ s/^[^\S\n]+[!\n]?//mg;
    print $message;
}
```

The above also remove the undesired blank leading line.

---

Finally, note that `r` modifier introduced in 5.14.

```
if ($send) {
    my $message = qq{
        !Dear $name,
        !
        !this is a message I plan to send to you.
        !
        !regards
        !  the Perl Maven
    } =~ s/^[^\S\n]+[!\n]?//mgr;
    print $message;
}
```

---

1. See [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129) for more on what the assignment operator returns.

Comment: For the time being the `{8}` was updated based on the indentation at the time. Using a "delimiter' moves around easier. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Matt, Sorry, it got removed by accident. It has been re-added.